# Wordepress - JQuery script working on the home but not on other pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This is my first entry on this site, but not my first us of it :)

So my problem is the next one, I have a Jquery script wich is pretty simple that allow me to scroll on my page depending on the menu entry.

```
(function($) {
   var menu = $('.navbar');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
  });

  $('.navbar a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var target = this.hash,
  $target = $(target);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
 'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
  }, 1000, 'swing', function() {
    window.location.hash = target;
  });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Till there it work really fine on my first page with the ancore on my nav.

**But** when I go to the other pages, there is a problem of loading maybe or I don't know what. The other codes are working and the Jquery to no errors in the console. This part is just not loaded.

*So could anyone help me to get through this please?*

Maybe a way to debug it or ust to figure out what's happenning.

Thanks community, have a great Chrismas party :)

Comment: The other pages means completely new page? This code should be loaded there too. Try copy pasting all of it on console of that 'other' page and see if it starts working.

Comment: I know, this is weird.

It is not working on other page even in the console, I tryed it.
I am gona try to put it in the corps of the page directly in the page builder to see how it work, I'll come back withe the result. 

But I don't have any other way to fix that.

I think this is something to do with the WP-theme wich is a one page that we transform into a multi page. I know this is a bad idear but I arrived in the middle of the process so I have to deal with it from where I start.

I'll come back with the result.

Thanks and happy new year !)

Adricen